# How enable a click event of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I disable a jQuery click event with:

```
$("#button").click( function () { return false;}
```

How can I enable it? The intention is avoid double clicks and run multiple times the function that triggers.
I want to restore the event when other button was pushed.

Comment: `$('#button').bind('click');` is this you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple options, but I like the following best:

```
//disable
$("#button").bind('click', function() { return false; });

//enable
$("#button").unbind('click');
```

You could also bind click again on the button to some other callback function as well. Lastly, I might suggest calling `preventDefault` on the event from a click event, depending on what `#button` really is like so:

```
$("#button").bind('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; 
});
```

As j08691 pointed out, as of jQuery 1.7 on, it should look like:

```
$("#button").on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$("#button").one('click', function () { /* code here */ });
```

The event will unbind itself after being called once.

Comment: But I want to bind it when other button was pushed.

Comment: Create a function that will bind to your first button like above, then whenever you want to "activate" the button, call that function. So in your case you'd call that function in the second button's `click()` event

Comment: I have tried that solution. $("#button").click( function () { return false;} to disable and $('#button').bind('click'); in other function to enable, but not work

Comment: If you use `one()` you won't have to manually unbind it. What about what you tried didn't work? You could also try storing a variable like `buttonEnabled` and check for that in your `click()` event. Return false if it's not true, else perform the rest of your code. You can set that var to control if your button is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
$("#button").unbind("click");
```

the button will be working again, the unbind function erases registered events handlers from the selected element, if you dont pass it an argument it will erase all events registered.

EDIT: as noted in the comments, you can use now the on and off methods:

```
$("#button").off("click")
```

to disable clicks and:

```
 $("#button").on("click")
```

to enable them again

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i didnt know about it.